# Как вывести максимальное значение в Map/Set

Tags: javascript

```
 let ma = new Set([[3],[5],[7]])
for(let i of ma){
    alert(Math.max(...i))

}
```

Что в моем коде неправильно? Также пробовал преобразовать в массив, но все равно не получалось

Comment: В реальности в Set значениями являются массивы с одним значением, а уже метод Math.max() преобразует эти массивы в числа, при этом сами массивы при таком преобразовании возвращают строки "3", "5" и "7", а уже метод преобразовывает эти строки в числа. Одним словом, это все - источник возможных ошибок. Если в реальности значениями множества должны быть числа, то и надо явно это делать: `const num_set = new Set([3,5,7])`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let ma = new Set([[3],[5],[7]])
    alert(Math.max(...ma))
```

Comment: А что можно было без цикла?(

Comment: @Ghost нужно было

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь в цикле получать максимальное значение, но на вход передаете только текущее значение.

То есть на первой итерации цикла передаете 3. И пытаетесь получить Math.max(3);

На второй итерации пытаетесь получить Math.max(5). И т.д.

Нужно передавать сразу весь массив значений.

```js
let ma = new Set([
  [3],
  [5],
  [7]
])

alert(Math.max(...ma))
```

Можно из Map сделать массив и получить максимальное значение

```js
let ma = new Map([
  [1, 3],
  [2, 5],
  [3, 7]
]);

// 1 способ
const arr = [];
ma.forEach(value => {
  arr.push(value)
});

console.log(Math.max(...arr));

// 2 способ
const arr2 = [...ma].map(([name, value]) => value);
console.log(Math.max(...arr2));

// 3 способ
console.log(Math.max(...ma.values()));
```

Как можно было заметить `Math.max()` работает с массивом данных. Поэтому если есть возможность хранить и обрабатывать данные в массиве - то стоит этим пользоваться. Советую изучить предназначение типов данных `массив`, `Map`, `Set`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понял. А с map как сделать не подскажете? Аналогично сделал:
```
let ma = new Map([[1,3],[2,5],[3,7]])
alert((Math.max(...ma.values)))
```

Comment: @Ghost Пожалуйста попрактикуйте  spreed  оператор.

Comment: @WalkMess сейчас этим и занимаюсь

Comment: @Chost Добавил преобразование Map в массив. С ним так не работает, так как это другая структура данных. Стоит обратить внимание и изучить структуры данных, чтобы понимать какая и для чего нужна

Comment: @Ghost, все правильно, только для получения значений нужно вызвать метод .values(), а в вашем случае вы пытаетесь проитерировать тело нативной функции прототипа Map ->  `Math.max(...ma.values())` Это работает как с Set, так и с Map. Потому что в данном случае Set - частный случай Map, у которого ключи совпадают со значениями.